# .html() returning empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery for my web application and I am creating a numeric updown box.  For this I am replacing an input `<input type="text">` field with a pre defined div.

Thing is I want to get the html of the original input box as it may have styles etc added that I would like my `.replaceWith` version to have also.

e.g.
Current code `<input type="text">`
New Code

```
<div>
   <input type="text">
   <div>
      <!-- Other Stuff -->
   </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see I need to regenerate the input control along side making a parent element.  The way I do this at present is just regenerate everything and use the `.replaceWith()` method to paste it all.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post the JQuery code you're using? Would make it easier to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you want to wrap a parent `div` around the `input`, and add another `div` after it. If that's the case, you can do something like this:

```
$("input").wrap("<div></div>").after("<div></div>");
```

This way, you don't need to replace the `input`, as it will stay in the DOM. [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) will wrap the argument around the selected element, and [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) will insert content after the selected element.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/n39cM/1/).

Comment: This is pretty much what I am looking for I want to add additional buttons to an input box so like this
<input type="myInput">  $("#myInput").addExtraStuff();  That class would wrap a div around it with another div appended to the input for the buttons

Answer (score 1):

Elements of type `input` don't really *contain* HTML, but rather, the `input` tag would be the HTML contained within its parent container (`div` in this case). So what you might consider is placing it in a dedicated inner container and remove and replace it in that.

Comment: I don't think the OP means the HTML of the `input` as in the contents, but rather then HTML that refers to the element itself, "as it may have styles etc added"

Comment: @JamesAllardice I don't mean the _contents_ either; I mean grabbing the HTML `<input ... />` itself _from_ a container. What I'm saying is, calling `html()` on `input` won't give you `<input .../>` - you would need to call it on its container.

Comment: @JamesAllardice No worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.html()` returns empty if you use it on an `<input>` element because it has no content, only attributes.

> Thing is I want to get the html of the original input box as it may have styles etc added

You can get the `style` and `class` attributes of the original input box and then apply them to your generated `<div>` element, e.g., something like this:

```
$("someselectorforyournewdiv").addClass( $("input").attr("class") );
// and/or
$("someselectorforyournewdiv").attr( "style", $("input").attr("style") );
```

(Obviously adjusting the selectors to suit.)

But won't your generated element have its own styles to make a nice "updown box"? If you apply the original styles from the input as well it might not work too well, unless you pick out certain styles that won't affect the shape, like the colour or that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using a wrong selector

give your input or whateever an id and then do like

```
$('input#yourid').replaceWith('Insert your desired html');
```

Reference [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 0):

An `<input />` element is not a container, therefore it will not have an HTML value. If you're after the text that was entered in the box, use the `.val()` method instead.

Comment: I don't think the OP means the HTML of the `input` as in the contents, but rather then HTML that refers to the element itself, "as it may have styles etc added"

Comment: @James Allardice Fair enough, but it seemed worth mentioning just in case.